# Building and construction calculations

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a website for building and construction calculations software (such as [CSI ETABS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Structures), XSteel/Tekla, [CSI SAP2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Structures), [CSI SAFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Structures), etc.) on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be a rather specific subject for a Stack Exchange site.

For general computer questions, you can go to [Super User](http://superuser.com). With luck, someone there has been using the same software that you have, and can answer any questions you have.

For questions specific to construction work, there is a [site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45232/building-performance-simulation-analysis) on Area 51. The site isn't there yet, but is far in the commitment phase.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think so.

But you can *propose* such a site on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). It might be a bit too specific to find enough followers/committers though.

Comment: *I can't find any website in Area51 for Building and Construction Calculations Software* that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Please read my answer again ;)

Answer (score 2):

Related question - [Building and Construction Calculations](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12726/building-and-construction-calculations)
Answer - No

You could try

1. [Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering)
2. [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)